# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\;\frac{nx}{n^2 x^2 +1}$ where $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

What is the limit of the function serie?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{n^2 x^2 +1},$$

where $x\in[0,1]$.

At the point $x=\frac{1}{n}$, the function takes its maximal value $1/2$. On the other hand, taking the limit, it seems that the limit is $0$.

Comment: You're taking the limit with respect to $n$ so $x=\tfrac1n$ is meaningless

Comment: @vrugtehagel Is this limit function continuous?

Comment: You discovered a sequence of functions converging pointwise but not uniformly.

Comment: I figured out how I was wrong. I thought the sequence was Cauchy in supremum norm. I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{nx}{n^2 x^2 +1}=\frac{x/n}{ x^2 +1/n} \to 0$  for each $x \in [0,1]$

Hence, the sequence of functions converges pointwise to $0$

Comment: I figured out how I was wrong. I thought the sequence was Cauchy in supremum norm. I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write your term in the form $$\frac{n}{n^2}\cdot \frac{x}{x^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$